# Rails naming convention for Uppercase names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model, naming

I've got a model class:

```
class QRCode < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :properties

end
```

So rails needs a database table named 'qr_codes' and a foreign key called 'qr_code_id'.
But as a relationship in my Property Model it needs another name:

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :q_r_code

end
```

So if I want to create a Property object I' have to say ':q_r_code => qrcode'
But active_record wants a qr_code property, because the column is called 'qr_code_id'

Do I understand something wrong or is this type of name impossible to map for Rails?

P.S.: I'm using Rails 3.0.3

Comment: I would rename my class `QrCode`. In other words I use the camel case to represent word boundaries, rather than the notion of whether or not the original term is an acronym or not.

Comment: This is one of the things that irritates me about using Rails with legacy databases. Field names are often coming from left-field because the original creator of the DB or table didn't stop to think about using a language to access the table other than SQL and the console. Considering an ORM with its rules and assumptions was completely beyond their scope.

As @Simone Carletti points out, Rails allows us to override its assumptions with the actual names of keys or tables, but we can still be left with awkwardly named models and fields, leading to some cursing as we ferret out the problems.

Comment: Thanks, finally I renamed my class to QrCode, because I can avoid this customization of relationships and routes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[belong_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to) accepts a `:foreign_key` and `:class_name` attribute.